# php HTTP File Upload variables are not always readable

Tags: http, file-upload, php-5.4

In PHP (Version 5.4.39-0+deb7u2) I upload files.
This went smooth for about 3 years, until today.

After hours of testing I noticed that the **$_FILES['Filedata']['name']** array is not readable when:

- the filename is written by a Mac OSX system when the PATHINFO_EXTENSION is '**.jpg**'
- files written as '.JPG' have no problems.
- when the filename contains '**-_**' (eg 20151126-_HG634163.JPG)
- files written on PC containing .jpg, .JPG, -_, ... are working perfect

Below the code that worked perfect until this morning. There were no server-changes.
Both Chrome and Safari gave the same results.
The ***$this->file_name*** variable is stored in a DB to prevent doubles.

```
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $this->file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
        $fileTypes = array('jpg','JPG','jpeg'); // File extensions
        $this->new_filename = $_POST['i']."_".date(YmdHis).$i."_".sha1($this->file)."_".rand(0, 1000)."_".rand(0, 1000).".JPG";
        $this->new_file = $this->targetFile."/".$this->new_filename;

        if (in_array($ext,$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$this->new_file);
        } else {
        $this->upload_error = 1;
        }
        }
```

Comment: You have `$_FILES['Files']` in your description, but `$_FILES['Filedata']` in your code.

Comment: I See, but this is not the issue.